# return file for download on click with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a website people can fill/upload necessary information in a form. Based on these information, the server does some computation, generates an output file and return the file. Everything goes well except the last step of returning. Following is a simplified version of my site that you can test directly. In this example, it should return a file containing the file name uploaded by the user while stay on the same page. However, it actually returns the html code of the page and the file name. What should I do to get only the output file not the html code? Thanks a lot!

I tried with flask, and everything went well. Now, for some reason I would like to translate everything to php. I am really new to website building and lack a lot of background knowledge.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div> Upload your file: <input type="file" name="file"/> </div>
    <input style="margin-left: 0.5em;" type="submit" id="click" 
           value="Click Me!" name='submit_btn'/>
    </form>

    <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
       {
          $fp = fopen("./output.txt", "w");
          fwrite($fp, $_FILES['file']['name']."\n");
          fclose($fp);

          header("Content-Type:text/plain");
          header("Content-Type: application/download");
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                 filename="output.txt"');
          readfile("output.txt");
       }
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: you cant change header after you print something to screen, copy your code to new php file and link that file at `action=`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return both HTML *and* a file.  Each HTTP request can result in only one or the other.  Separate your concerns.  Start with a PHP resource which *only* returns the file you posted to it:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
   {
      $fp = fopen("./output.txt", "w");
      fwrite($fp, $_FILES['file']['name']."\n");
      fclose($fp);

      header("Content-Type:text/plain");
      header("Content-Type: application/download");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
             filename="output.txt"');
      readfile("output.txt");
   }
?>
```

Then write an HTML page which posts to that PHP resource:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="yourPHPFileAbove.php" method="POST" autocomplete="on" 
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div> Upload your file: <input type="file" name="file"/> </div>
            <input style="margin-left: 0.5em;" type="submit" id="click" 
                   value="Click Me!" name='submit_btn'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note specifically how the `action` attribute in the `<form>` posts to a specific PHP resource, not just back to itself.